# Capturar tecla pulsada Android

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para Android y necesito capturar las teclas que se pulsen en el teclado. Soy nueva programando en Xamarin y me ayudaría mucho si alguien pudiera orientarme.

Answer (score 4):

Lo común es realizarlo con el método [**onKeyDown()**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnKeyDown/p/Android.Views.Keycode/Android.Views.KeyEvent/),

por ejemplo si deseamos detectar cuando se da click en la tecla "Back":

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        //Implemenetar accción,Se pulso la tecla back!
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

- información método [**onKeyDown()**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnKeyDown/p/Android.Views.Keycode/Android.Views.KeyEvent/) Xamarin (inglés):

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnKeyDown/p/Android.Views.Keycode/Android.Views.KeyEvent/

- Aquí puedes encontrar un listado de todas las constantes, para detectar cualquier tecla:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

- También puedes utilizar el métodod [onKeyUp()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnKeyUp/p/Android.Views.Keycode/Android.Views.KeyEvent/), pero la diferencia es que este se ejecuta al soltar la tecla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su pronta respuesta, lo probaré

Answer (score 0):

> Para eventos de teclado en Xamarin Android debes de implementar la interfaz **[KeyEvent.ICallback](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html)**.

La interfaz tiene estos métodos:

- OnKeyDown(int,KeyEvent)
- OnKeyLongPress(int,KeyEvent)
- OnKeyMultiple(int,int,KeyEvent)
- OnKeyUp(int,KeyEvent)

Documentación KeyEvent Android de Xamarin: [Enlace](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.KeyEvent/)

Si estas en una Activity, tendrías que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MiActivity : Activity , KeyEvent.ICallback
{ 
    public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        //codigo asociado a la key presionada
        return base.OnKeyUp(keyCode, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cuando me dices implementar la interfaz, disculpa, es que estoy comenzando. Podrias ponerme un ejemplo